# Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported—when following the ASP.NET tutorial on MS Docs

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

## Context

I'm following [Microsoft's tutorial on MVC in ASP.NET Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), using VS Code and the terminal, and I got stuck on [the Initial Migration step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#initial-migration-1).

There are numerous similar questions on SO, but none of them contain an answer I can understand, as this is my first dive into ASP.NET.

## Problem Description

The tutorial asks that I run the following commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

The first one ran without a hitch. The second results in the following error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentException: Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.
```

## Setup

Here's my `appsettings.json` file, the one with the connection string:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMovieContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcMovieContext-9dffe5a0-829d-4c64-9129-54ea0791196d;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

And here's `appsettings.Development.json`, which lacks any connection string:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding the `"AllowedHosts"` and `"ConnectionString"` entries to this file, since I'd think I should be in development mode right now, but it didn't change anything.

If I understand this right, my **project is using SQLite in development and SQLServer in production**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddDbContext<MvcMovieContext>(options =>
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext");

        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            options.UseSqlite(connectionString);
        else
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    });
}
```

Finally, here's my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.11">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite" Version="5.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If you'd like to see other parts of the code, [I've hosted the project on GitHub](https://github.com/dsaghliani/MvcMovie-tutorial). Alternatively, you can let me know and I'll put it up.

Comment: If you're ever not sure what format a connection string needs to be in for the type of DB, then [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite is not a server based database; the provider you're using for it doesn't understand the `Server` keyword you've used in the connection string. Try specifying `Data Source=some_path`.

For a list of valid keywords, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings

Side note: SQLServer's provider understands `Server` as a synonym of `Data Source`

If you remove/fix one keyword it doesn't like you'll see the error has shifted to complaining about the next one (`Database`); in essence it's to be expected if you're trying to use a SQLServer flavored connection string (which would reasonably have `Server` and `Database` keywords) with SQLite.

You can also take a look at connectionstrings.com for some examples of connstrs for each DB and form the relevant strings approriately - ultimately, these two DBs have very different needs when it comes to what keywords you use in the conenction strings.

It's probably going to be simplest to just have two strings:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMovieContextSQLS": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcMovieContext-9dffe5a0-829d-4c64-9129-54ea0791196d;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "MvcMovieContextSQLite": "Data Source=c:\path\to\my.db"
  }
```

And your code pulls them appropriately:

```
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContextSQLite"));
    else
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContextSQLS"));
```

Or if you're deciding that "dev is SQLite and live is SQLS" you can have your development config override your main config by specifying the same group (ConnectionStrings) and attribute (MvcMovieContext) in appsettings.Development.json:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMovieContext": "Data Source=c:\path\to\my.db"
  }
```

I tend not to go this route, for various reasons, but it's perfectly valid if you remember that the `appsettings.Development.json` replaces any matching elements in `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Thanks. Although, did you mean `DataSource` (without spaces)? I changed it to that in `appsettings.Development.json` and that specific error's gone. Now, I'm told, "Connection string keyword 'database' is not supported." What do I replace *that* with?

Comment: `Datasource` is an alias/synonym of `Data Source`

Comment: Similar reason; the `Data Source` setting nominates the sqlite db file (or maybe youre using in-mem and don't have a file), you don't need a `database` keyword (and the provider doesn't support it) - it's for systems like SQLServer where one Server hosts multiple Databases

Comment: (The solution is, in essence, there in the error message: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181)

Comment: Once I removed that, it kept complaining about `Trusted_Connection` and `MultipleActiveResultSets`, so I removed those, too. Now: "SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'." And I did go to the site mentioned, but searching for the keyword "Server"—which was causing the error—gave me no results, so I gave up and decided to ask.

Comment: So, all in, do you understand that your connection string for SQLite is going to have to look like e.g. `Data Source=c:\temp\my.db` and for SQLServer like `Data Source=somesqlserver;Initial Catalog=somedb;User ID=someuid;Password=somepw` - i.e. *completely different* - you'll need two settings

Comment: (Side note 2: Many things in connection strings are synonymous. For a SQLServer connstr `Data Source, Server, Addr, Address, Network Address` all mean the same thing: the server to connect to. Even if there is crossover though, like both providers supporting `Data Source` you're still better off just providing different strings rather than trying to find a way to make one string work for two different DB providers

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't really understand. Until a few minutes ago, I didn't even know what connection strings were. I never explicitly created any database files, either. The tutorial never mentioned anything like that, and as I said, I'm completely new to this. Literally on the 3rd step—the first migration. It leads me to question the integrity of Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: Many people complain about MS' documentation; I dare say it's pretty good considering the herculean task of documenting an ever shifting ecosystem that they create but it will probably come up lacking in areas. So.. A conenction string is just a list of Key=Value pairs that the driver needs to conenct the DB. Different drivers support different keywords, and some keywords are synonymous. Put two settings in your json, called different things, with different connstrs in each, and then adjust the code to use them approriately. I'll suggest in an edit

Comment: Thank you. ~Do I have to create the `.db` file on my system, or will the `ef` tool write to it automatically?~ It did so automatically. Now, I just gotta hope deviating from the tutorial's step so much won't make it impossible to follow it.

Comment: Heh, get ready for some more magic then; You'll have created a bunch of classes that link to each other; Movies that have lists of actors etc, then you'll run one command and pow.. a boatload of database tables appear, all wired up together and ready to use. It's wonderful, but also a little "how does the gremlin inside the black box work?" - an exercise for another day though..